# How to optimize Flutter UI profile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't know why my flutter apk flutter profile UI is too much high. could anyone please help me to solve the problem....[image]

Answer (score 0):

The raster thread is taking a long time in your case, which means something in your code is causing bottlenecks in rendering.

Common causes include having multiple `Opacity` widgets (especially `AnimatedOpacity` or `FadeTransition`), clipping widgets (like `ClipRect`, `ClipRRect`, `ClipOval`, and `ClipPath` widget), etc. If you are using `CustomPaint` or writing custom `RenderObject`, check if you are calling `saveLayer` a lot. It's also possible that you are using too big images. For example, for user profile pictures, try to use images that are smaller than 200x200 in size, and see if it helps.